# QDate - wrong year

Tags: qt, qdate

I have the following situation:

```
   QDate fixDate = QDate::fromString(QString("270912"), "ddMMyy");
```

the year returned is `1912`. I do not understand why and how get the correct year.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Qt always interprets a two-digit year as `19yy`.
So it's best to modify the input string to look like `YYYY`.

Note: parsing it as YY and adding 100 years fails on Feb 29, 2000. '22900' is seen as February 29, 1900, but - surprise! - in the Gregorian calendar 1900 is not a leap year. So you get an invalid QDate, which remains invalid after adding 100 years to it.

Comment: Sorry, QT internal documentation does not mention this, but this is usual behaivour of two-digit year interpretators.
Qdate::fromString("01", "yy") returns 1901 f.e.

[code]QDate fixDate = QDate::fromString(QString("270912"), "ddMMyy").addYears(100);[/code] will solve Your problem

Comment: In a way I find this behaviour reasonable. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdate.html#fromString):

```
For any field that is not represented in the format the following defaults are used:
Year 1900
Month 1
Day 1

// For example:
QDate::fromString("1.30", "M.d");           // January 30 1900
QDate::fromString("20000110", "yyyyMMdd");  // January 10, 2000
```

(Excuse the formatting, it's in a table in the docs).  So you are going to have to pass the full year into the method until Qt decide 2012 is far enough into the century to change the default...

Comment: I see. I am reading that particular string from an nmea sentence. So I do not want to tamper it

Comment: Well you are going to have to tweak the `QDate` output then otherwise you're stuck in the last century!

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `ddMMyyyy` instead of `ddMMyy`? Or you need date in this format?

[Look here for more information about fromString method](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdate.html#fromString)